# Adding simple delay to JavaScript code without using external libraries

Tags: javascript, delay

A quick question, tell me please how to add delay to this code.

I guess it is super simple, but I am new to JavaScript.
I think the answer is somewhere in the beginning within the duration variable.

Here is JavaScript code:

```
var modern = requestAnimationFrame, duration = 400, initial, aim;

window.smoothScroll = function(target) {
var header = document.querySelectorAll('.aconmineli');
    aim = -header[0].clientHeight;
    initial = Date.now();

  var scrollContainer = document.getElementById(target);
  target = document.getElementById(target);

    do {
    scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
    if (!scrollContainer) return;
    scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    }
    while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

    do {
    if (target == scrollContainer) break;
    aim += target.offsetTop;
    }
    while (target = target.offsetParent);

    scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {

        if (modern) {
        var present = Date.now(),
        elapsed = present-initial,
        progress = Math.min(elapsed/duration, 1);
        c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) * progress;
        if (progress < 1) requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        scroll(c, a, b, i);
        });
        }
        else {
        i++; if (i > 30) return;
        c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
        setTimeout(function() {scroll(c, a, b, i)}, 20);
        }
    }

    scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, aim, 0);
}
```

By the way it is a great pure JavaScript only code for scrolling on clicking.

Comment: change that `20` at line `setTimeout(function() {scroll(c, a, b, i)}, 20);`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it doesn't work, already tried it once, now i tried it twice... still doesn't change...

Comment: I do agree changing setTimeout last parameter will do the trick. What you must consider is that that parameter is in milliseconds. Thus if you change it from 20 to 21 you will notice nothing. Change it to 2000 and let's see what happen

Comment: I don't know what kind of delay are you trying to achieve. Wrap the whole function body into `setTimeout(..., 1000);`

Comment: Thank you Alencar, but i already told you i have tried twice, and i am aware that this is milliseconds. Drinovc would you be please more specific how and what do i have to wrap? i have tried several formations whit setTimeout(function(){ ............... }, 3000); whit no luck..

Comment: There are also few mistakes in this code. You must use `==` here: `while (target = target.offsetParent);` Missing semicolons, no indention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var modern = requestAnimationFrame,
    duration = 400,
    initial,
    aim,
    delay = 1000;

window.smoothScroll = function(target) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.doSmoothScroll(target);
    }, delay);
};

window.doSmoothScroll = function(target) {
    var header = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar');
    aim = -header[0].clientHeight;
    initial = Date.now();

    var scrollContainer = document.getElementById(target);
    target = document.getElementById(target);

    do {
        scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
        if (!scrollContainer) return;
        scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    }
    while (scrollContainer.scrollTop === 0);

    do {
        if (target == scrollContainer) break;
        aim += target.offsetTop;
    }
    while (target == target.offsetParent);

    scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {

        if (modern) {
            var present = Date.now(),
                elapsed = present - initial,
                progress = Math.min(elapsed / duration, 1);
            c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) * progress;
            if (progress < 1) requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                scroll(c, a, b, i);
            });
        } else {
            i++;
            if (i > 30) return;
            c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
            setTimeout(function() {
                scroll(c, a, b, i);
            }, 20);
        }
    };

    scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, aim, 0);
};
```

Comment: May be something like this, i think you should see the jsfiddle, when i update your code, it doesnt work. http://jsfiddle.net/sjx0c7sz/1/

Comment: I forgot to pass the arguments. Updated.